# PHP: Reference another static variable inside a static variable

Tags: php, reference, static

Either I'm too dumb or this is somehow not possible in [php](/questions/tagged/php) (which is really a basic functionality in any programming language...):
So here's the example for my problem:

```
class Test {
 private static $A = "test";
 private static $B = "This is a " . Test::$A . " to see if it works";
}
```

My expected result is the variable `$B` to have the value = `This is a test to see if it works`

But somehow I'm getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$A' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or class (T_CLASS) in /.../class.Test.php on line 4

Is this something [php](/questions/tagged/php) is unable to do or is it just some stupid typo? I'm unable to find the error since like an hour...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Class properties can't have dynamic values. Meaning you can't do what you just did. Use `__construct` to set dynamic values for properties. Or setters, whichever tickles your fancy.

Comment: In which programming language can you do what you did. I don't think you can in any...

Comment: Well there is for instance no problem doing that in Java. I don't see how these values are dynamic. It's clearly static. The variable $A will ALWAYS have the same value so i just can't understand why this can't be achieved the way i've put it. But i'm kinda new to php so i'll just trust you that it's not possible this way (i'll just have 1 more reason to avoid php where i can :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution if you don't want to have another clas

```php
class TestStatic
{
    private static $A = 'test';
    private static $B;

    //if you want to instantiate the object
    public function __construct() {
        self::setB();
    }

    //if you don't want to instantiate the class 
    public static function getB() {
        self::setB();
       return self::$B;
    }

    private static function setB() {
       if (!isset(self::$B)) {
        self::$B = 'This is a '.self::$A.' to see if it works';
    }
}
```

}

```
echo TestStatic::getB();
```

Comment: Thanks! This comes as close as i'd like it to have. Still a shame it doesn't work my way :)

Answer (score 0):

1. **You can't assign dynamic value to class property**. See [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)
2. You can try to define magic getter, BUT **getters don't work with static properties**. See [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get)

> Property overloading only works in object context. These magic methods
>   will not be triggered in static context. Therefore these methods
>   should not be declared static. As of PHP 5.3.0, a warning is issued if
>   one of the magic overloading methods is declared static.
>
> In PHP 5.3, __callStatic has been added ; but there is no __getStatic
>   nor __setStatic

3. So only options that I see is to **use __callStatic and access to you properties via static magic methods.** See example below.

   ```
   class A {

      public static $A = 'A';

      public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
      {
         if ($name== 'B') {
            return B::$B;
         }
      }

   }

   class B {
       public static $B = 'B';
   }

   echo A::B(); // return 'B'
   ```